# AXI4 throughput on FPGA

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm working on a 7 series FPGA, and am planning to use MIG memory controller for interface with DDR3, and an AXI4 interface between memory controller and the other modules inside the FPGA. What sort of throughput efficiency will I get, say if I run it at some X clock and 64-bit data. What I mean is 64X is illogical to assume. What fraction of it is lost in handshaking for burst mode and a non-burst mode? I'm just looking for rough values, not exact. Something in the ballpark.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Xilinx's [xapp792](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp792-high-performance-video-zynq.pdf) 70% efficiency is a reasonable number. This is for video which generally has very burstable DDR SDRAM friendly access patterns.  Random memory access will probably be far less.